# ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ... NOT NULL is not instant in PostgreSQL 11?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, online-operations

I have read the documentation and it states that adding a column with a non-null and non-volatile default value should not require a table rewrite. However, this does require a rewrite and blocks all SELECTs:

```
ALTER TABLE sales ADD COLUMN bar DECIMAL(18, 4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

On a 300gb table this will block for several hours as it's rewritten. Am I missing something?

```
postgres=> select version();
                                                 version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but it's an AWS RDS instance.

Comment: Can you show link to documentation that says that?

Comment: That must be an Amazon thing, since [it works in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html): *When a column is added with `ADD COLUMN` and a non-volatile `DEFAULT` is specified, the default is evaluated at the time of the statement and the result stored in the table's metadata. That value will be used for the column for all existing rows. If no `DEFAULT` is specified, NULL is used. In neither case is a rewrite of the table required.*

Comment: Are you sure it is actually doing a rewrite, and not just blocked on the ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock it needs?

Comment: It's definitely doing a rewrite, I can see 20mb/s write for 46 minutes. I also tested during that time that any SELECT was blocked against that table. I didn't think RDS was modified from vanilla PostgreSQL, only a wrapper to handle the tedious ops parts?